# add a column to an existing Table in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a swing application in which I can fetch the data from the database and display it in a table by using rs2xml.jar.

Here is my code:

```
package swing_demo_app;

//import in.teamnet.utils.DbUtils;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author ankitparmar
 */
public class NewTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewTable
     */

    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pre=null;


    public NewTable() {
        initComponents();
        conn=DBEngine.getConnection();
        update_table();

    }
    private void update_table(){
        try {
            String sql="SELECT * FROM ierm.wcmap";
            pre=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pre.executeQuery();
            Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            Table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to add a column in this existing table.. 
Can any one point me to a right direction ?

Comment: [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) has [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel%28%29), there is method [addColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#addColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29), note there is difference between methods implemented in JTable and TableColumnModel's APIs

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing

- `Table` is a `JTable`
- `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` return a `TableModel` or similar.

Get the model of the database, but don't add it to table

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
```

Add a new column to table

```
tableModel.addColumn(newColumnName);
```

And set the model to the table

```
jTable.setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: @ArchanaSarang great to hear that!  ;)