# add a column to an existing Table from SQL using DbUtils

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am developing a swing application in which I can fetch the data from the database and display it in a table by using rs2xml.jar.

Here is my code:

```
try{ 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","","");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID LIKE ? AND FullName LIKE ? AND Telephone LIKE ? AND Email LIKE ?" ); 
            statement.setString(1, '%'+ID1+'%');
            statement.setString(2, '%'+FullName1+'%');
            statement.setString(3, '%'+Telephone1+'%');
            statement.setString(4, '%'+Email1+'%');
            ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(set));

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
       }
```

Now, I need to add a column in this existing table using other Query.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246256/add-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-swing) but i am getting this error:
**Type mismatch: cannot convert from TableModel to DefaultTableModel**

Any Ideas please?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the _full stack trace_? we can not analyze your error from just the first line.

Comment: Roll your own `TableModel`, populate it from the `ResultSet` yourself and gain full control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from TableModel to DefaultTableModel

You can't just assign a `TableModel` to a `DefaultTableMOdel`.

Assuming `DBUtils` creates a `DefaultTableModel` then you need to "cast" the `TableModel` to a `DefaultTableModel`.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addColumn(...);
```